Line containing embedded Nulls and Encoding with Incomplete ending
For an election project I'm pulling data from the North Carolina elections website into a Rmarkdown file. This is the code I've been using to download it:
library(tidyverse)
read.delim("https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl.ncsbe.gov/ENRS/2020_11_03/results_precinct_sort/PAMLICO_PRECINCT_SORT.txt", row.names = NULL)

When I do, no matter what file from the site I download, I get the error line _ appears to contain embedded nulls for lines 2-5. When I tried the most common fix which is applying a UTF-16LE fileEncoding I get a different error incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on. Does anyone know what's going on or what the best way to work around this would be?
I am able to read in the file otherwise with the majority of the rows and values but this question has been bothering me. Every row should have the same formatting but rows 2-5 of the file are different. I've seen some other solutions for csv files but if I'm pulling from a .txt file which I can't edit the options are a bit more limited.

I just downloaded the file and there are definitely null bytes in there. Is there documentation for these files somewhere describing the file format? Like do these values have special meaning? What columns do you actually need from this data? It's not a general encoding problem. It seems like just a bad data dump.

You call library(tidyverse) but you are still using the base R read.delim(). You can also use read_delim() instead. That seems to be more robust to the invalid values. It seems like the content_party_lbl values are just all invalid.

There was a text file (https://dl.ncsbe.gov/ENRS/layout_results_pct.txt) which had some of the information but using read_delim() made it work! Thanks for the advice as I didn't realize the difference between the _ and the .
